# Why does my random function doesn't always work?

Tags: clojure

My function is supposed to give me 6 numbers, but to avoid zero and should not repeat any number, but sometimes it brings me 0 or repeated numbers

```
(defn function
  []
  (def lista (sort (take 6 (repeatedly #(rand-int 60)))))
  (loop []
    (when (or (= (contains? (set lista) 0) true) (< (count (set lista)) 6))
      (def lista (sort (take 6 (repeatedly #(rand-int 60)))))))
  (println lista))
```

Comment: Just as a side note, I'd recommend reading a good introduction into Clojure. Your use of `when` and `def` are inappropriate. It looks like you're trying to write Java in Clojure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve your problem you dont need that function. you can take a random 10 and call on set function to remove duplicates and filter ponly for positive numbers and take 6 from it.
code goes something like this. 20 is just a random sample

```
(take 6 (filter pos? (set (take 20 (repeatedly #(rand-int 60))))))
```

or

`(->>
 #(rand-int 60)
 (repeatedly)
 (take 20)
 (set)
 (filter pos?)
 (take 6) )`

Comment: Better to use `distinct` than `set` to remove the duplicates. Then you can maintain laziness and there's no need for the `(take 20)` step (which, theoretically might not even return 6 distinct non-zero elements!).  `(take 6 (filter pos? (distinct (repeatedly #(rand-int 60)))))`